# Namespacing in Ruby require

Tags: ruby, namespaces

Suppose I have a module, `mod.rb`

```
# mod.rb

def foo
  puts 'it'
end
```

And in another ruby file, `main.rb` I require it and use the function `foo`.

```
# main.rb

require('mod')

foo
```

When requiring multiple modules, this can make code hard to read because I don't really know where 'foo' is coming from.  Is there any idiomatic way to namespace these things in Ruby for the purpose of readability?  I am new to the language, and contributing to a project.  It took a lot of investigative work to find out which methods came from where.  If I wanted to contribute more by improving the readability, what would be a good approach?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in an actual `module` or `class`?

Comment: In situations where I'm inheriting from a base class, it made things much more readable to say `self.foo`.  I suppose I would just do `ClassName.foo`, or `ModuleName.foo` if following your suggestion.  Is that correct?  Is this the only reasonable way to do this?

Comment: Yes. What else would you like to be able to do?

Comment: That's it.  I guess that was easy.  If you care to make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to wrap your code in an actual `module` or `class`

something like

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    "quxx"
  end
end
```

This way, you will be able to call `Foo.bar` to access your method.

Comment: Without explaining modules/classes in details, I suggest to use `Module` instead of `Class` and `extend self` instead of defining it via `def self.*`. Few advantages: you can `include` module into some class (so you can use it as method of some object), you don’t have to write `self.` every time, and of course you can use `Foo.bar` convention.